# 404 Error Upon Uploading Objects to Google Cloud Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to upload files to google cloud bucket through google cloud console, but I am getting 'Something went wrong' error on UI. Following is the response error I am receiving:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "No such object: thesis_experience/Abdul Hameed-61058 a.f lecturer.txt"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "No such object: thesis_experience/Abdul Hameed-61058 a.f lecturer.txt"
 }
}
```

I have uploaded many files earlier as well, but I have no clue why is this happening to me now. I tried to create new buckets and upload files there too, but receiving the same error.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your issue to no avail. I tried uploading a single file with the same name as yours and later I tried it with your same structure, but I was able to upload it. Could you tell us: is this still on-going? when did it happen? how did you try to upload it? Did you successfully upload *other* files to *other* buckets?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was able to upload my files the next day. It seemed a temporary glitch to me that got resolved automatically.